# Ingresar datos a firestore con permisos limitados (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Actualmente tengo una APP con formularios los cuales tienen base de datos en firestore, el problema es que solo me deja ingresar datos con los permisos abiertos (allow read, write;), cuando cambio a privado no puedo hacerlo (allow read, write: if request.auth.uid !=null;). Tengo todo integrado con firebase authentication sin embargo de igual forma no puedo. Este es el codigo de mi formulario...

```
fun saveFireStore(nombre: String, Fecha: Int, respuestaq: String, respuestaq2: String, respuestaq3: String, respuestaq4: String, respuestaq5: String, respuestaq6: String, respuestaq7: String, respuestaq8: String, respuestaq9: String, respuestaq10: String, respuestaq11: String, respuestaq12: String, respuestaq13: String, respuestaq14: String) {

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val user: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    user["Nombre"] = nombre
    user["Fecha"] = Fecha
    user["El Arnes Presenta Estiramiento Excesivo"] = respuestaq
    user["El Arnes Presenta Rotura de tejido"] = respuestaq2
    user["El Arnés Presenta Fibras Externas Cortadas, Desgastadas/Desgarradas"] = respuestaq3
    user["El Arnés Presenta Quemaduras"] = respuestaq4
    user["El Arnés Presenta Deterioro General"] = respuestaq5
    user[" Las Argollas Presentan Defectos de Funcionamiento"] = respuestaq6
    user["Las Argollas Presentan Deformaciones (dobladuras) y Desgaste Excesivo"] = respuestaq7
    user[" Las Argollas Presentan Corrosión"] = respuestaq8
    user[" Las Argollas Presentan Grietas, Trizaduras"] = respuestaq9
    user["Las Argollas Presentan Defectos de Funcionamiento"] = respuestaq10
    user["Las Colas de Vida Presentan Estiramiento o Elongación Excesivos"] = respuestaq11
    user["Las Colas de Vida Presentan Desgaste, Deformación o Desgarro"] = respuestaq12
    user["Las Colas de Vida Presentan Cortes, Rotura del Tejido o Destrenzadas"] = respuestaq13
    user["Las Colas de Vida Presentan Quemaduras"] = respuestaq14

    db.collection("Lista Control Arnés")
            .add(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity32, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity32, "Falló", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
}
```

Comment: estás seguro que hay un usuario autenticado?

Comment: Si, al menos tengo el login screen en el mail activity, quizás tendré que enlazar ese login en el resto de los activities de alguna forma?

Comment: No, eso no hace falta. Si la autenticación está bien implementada, se mantiene a través de toda la aplicación. Prueba imprimir `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.toString()`. Si te da `null` significa que implementaste mal el login